# Fallo al redireccionar en una promesa

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promesas

Buen día.

Estoy realizando un script en el cual por medio de ajax realizo un proceso de inserción en BD dependiendo de lo que devuelva esta función ajax necesito recargar la misma pagina o limpiar el formulario, si todo sale bien continua con otra función ajax en la cual redirrecciona a otra pagina.

Mi problema es que independientemente del resultado de la primera función siempre redirecciona a la dirección de la segunda función y necesito que si no se cumple la condición en la primera llamada ajax recargue la misma pagina pero en este caso continua con la ejecución.

Estoy utilizando "promesas". Alguna idea, sugerencia para realizar esto o bien alguna manera que sea mejor?

Dejo mi código para que puedan ver lo que intento.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btnRegistroExamen").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $("#Userid").text(),
        FechaExamen = $("#Fechas").val(),
        FolioP = $("#FolioP").val(),
        FechaPago = $("#fechaP").val(),
        name = $("#nombre").val(),
        lastName = $("#Apellidos").val(),
        semestre = $("#Semestre").val(),
        carrera = $("#Carrera").val(),
        email = $("#email").val(),
        nControl = $("#Nctrl").val();

    var datos = {
        "id": id,
        "FechaExamen": FechaExamen,
        "FolioP": FolioP,
        "FechaPago": FechaPago
    }
    var completeData = {
        "id": id,
        "FechaExamen": FechaExamen,
        "FolioP": FolioP,
        "FechaPago": FechaPago,
        "nombre": name,
        "apellido": lastName,
        "semestre": semestre,
        "carrera": carrera,
        "email": email,
        "nControl": nControl
    };


    var Registro = $.ajax({
        url: "php/RegistrarExamen.php",
        data: datos,
        method: "POST",
        beforeSend: function () {
            console.log("Enviando datos");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Excito en envio de info...");
            if (!data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert(data);
                location.reload();
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("Fallo en envio");
        }
    });

    Registro.promise().done(function () {
        //Generacion de QR
        $.ajax({
            url: "php/qrGenerator.php",
            data: completeData,
            method: "POST",
            beforeSend: console.log("Enviando QR"),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    location.href = `RExamenExito.php?id=${id}`;
                } else {
                    console.log("Error en generacion de QR");
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("Error en QR");
            }
        });
    });
});
});
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda y comentarios.

Saludos.

Comment: Te lo ejecuta siempre porque le estás diciendo que cuando el primer ajax esté hecho (".done()") ejecute el siguiente independientemente del resultado que devuelva. Creo que para este caso no se debería usar promesas o yo no sabría cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Comprendo eso, lo que me causa problema es el porque si entra a la condición del primer ajax no recarga la pagina simplemente lo ignora y pasa al siguiente. Las promesas una alternativa que creí viable para este caso. Gracias por tu respuesta @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia

Comment: Vamos por partes, primero no veo la comprobación de la condición y segundo no te hace falta una promesa para lo que quieres hacer, ya que simplemente puedes hacer la segunda llamada Ajax dentro de la primera llamada. Lo importante es saber a que condición te refieres

Comment: @lDanny7 La condicion simplemente espera una bandera como indicador si se realizo la inserción de datos en la BD  en el "success" del primer ajax. Tu segundo punto te refieres a llamadas ajax anidadas? Esto no podria causar conflicto al realizar una segunda llamada sin haber concluido la primera?

Comment: Has mirado que te llega en data? Porque creo que si no es un false nunca entra en esa condición.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

según el comentario entiendo que tu condición es !data, que si es nulo o vacio haga un reload a la página. Comentas si realizando llamadas Ajax anidadas pueden causar conflicto, para que no ocurra eso esta el callback success que nos indica que la primera llamada ajax ha terminado por lo que puedes realizar la siguiente.

```
var Registro = $.ajax({
    url: "php/RegistrarExamen.php",
    data: datos,
    method: "POST",
    beforeSend: function () {
        console.log("Enviando datos");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("Excito en envio de info...");
        if (!data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert(data);
            location.reload();
        }
        else{
            $.ajax({
                        url: "php/qrGenerator.php",
                        data: completeData,
                        method: "POST",
                        beforeSend: console.log("Enviando QR"),
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data) {
                                location.href = `RExamenExito.php?id=${id}`;
                            } else {
                                console.log("Error en generacion de QR");
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            console.log("Error en QR");
                        }
                    });
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("Fallo en envio");
    }
});
```

Me parece que con esto te tendría que funcionar, pero la verdad que el código queda poco legible por lo que es mejor hacer la segunda llamada en otra función. Ejemplo:

```
var Registro = $.ajax({
    url: "php/RegistrarExamen.php",
    data: datos,
    method: "POST",
    beforeSend: function () {
        console.log("Enviando datos");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("Excito en envio de info...");
        if (!data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert(data);
            location.reload();
        }
        else{
            ajaxGenerarQR(completeData);
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("Fallo en envio");
    }
});

function ajaxGenerarQR(completeData)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "php/qrGenerator.php",
        data: completeData,
        method: "POST",
        beforeSend: console.log("Enviando QR"),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                location.href = `RExamenExito.php?id=${id}`;
            } else {
                console.log("Error en generacion de QR");
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("Error en QR");
        }
    }); 
}
```

Espero que te funcione

Comment: Efectivamente funciona correctamente, te lo agradezco mucho @Danny7